# Gitlab: Don't copy all labels from issue to merge-request

Tags: gitlab

If I create a merge-request from an issue, the MR gets the labels from the issue.

That's nice for most labels, but we have scoped labels "Workflow::....".

These Workflow-labels should not get copied from the issue to the MR.

Is there a way to configure gitlab accordingly?

We run on premise: GitLab Enterprise Edition 13.12.11-ee

Comment: show answer: no. You can file a feature request if there's no existing one: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/new?issuable_template=Feature%20Proposal%20-%20lean

Comment: @Arty-chan I created a feature request: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/341733

Comment: I've added labels so that it should get triaged properly